# Use git (or any vcs) within a web application

Tags: web-applications, database-design, version-control

We have a collection of simple texts in a git repository. This simple texts are formatted (LaTeX) and contain meta-information (author, ...).

We have tools to select some of those texts and have them published into a PDF document (to build a book containing user chosen texts). Those tools are today a desktop application and command line tools.

We are working on the design of a web application (foreseen language: python with django) to do the same job. Simply put : let users select some of the texts, order them, and have a downloadable PDF generated. Users should also have the possibility to modify or create new texts.

We want that the text collection remain common with that used by desktop application and command line users.

We see two possibilities regarding the handling of the texts:

- we keep the git repository as part of the web application. We benefit from versioning and synchronisation with the other tools and their users. We though need to interface from the web application to the git repo (commits, history) and probably will have to cache/index some information in a sql-like db (like authors, ...) for performance.

or

- we transfer all texts into a db. We do not need to interface with the repository within the web app, and have a classical web-app design. On the other hand, we face the problem of synchronizing from time to time to the git repository to make changes available to the rest of the world and fetch changes done otherwise.

Do someone has experience or recommandation, dos and donts regarding the use of a vcs/filesystem as part of the db in a web application?

Comment: A while ago we built a homework turn in system where files can be turned in via Mercurial or a web interface, and instructors can manage assignments completely in Mercurial or in a web interface. We ended up writing a bunch of Python libraries for VCS management with some help of writing to working copies from `hglib`. I guess it worked out more or less like you'd expect: reading lots of stuff from lots of repositories can get pretty slow, so you cache what makes sense in the database. You have to be wary of race conditions/corruption especially if you are writing to repositories as well.